# Internet memes and psychological warfare? Is there a way to determine what is and isn't a good idea?

Tags: science-based, warfare, psychology

So, whenever something meme-related stuff happens in a battle scene, I explain it with a catch-all excuse:

### Psychological Warfare

While there is some novelty in [using cheap holographic (read: smart fill and smudge) disguise to replace a charging mech/titan with Mio Honda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-VBnmsXiOw), I'm not sure if it adds extra intimidation to it. The same goes for playing earr ape music while charging the enemy or T-posing on corpses...

You get it, I don't know how can I determine which meme in what form is good for psyops. Should I play [Wagner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZ_zNUmr8fM) or [Tchaikovsky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbxgYlcNxE8) while peppering the enemy with lead from a helicopter? Should I use Pepe badges or whip out my makeup-kit and put Zergface on my soldiers? What about spray-painting Punisher's symbol on walls?

Wait, what do you mean [it has been done before](https://www.cbr.com/punisher-history-logo-used-police-military-politicians/)? Oh, you copy-cating little pieces of < omitted >

**Is there any guideline/rule that could help me determine what internet memes in what form will be effective (terrify the enemy without violating human rights too much) against a given enemy?**

In terms of context, a foreign, invading power with military superiority wants to flex on the enemy troops directly until they don't want to fight anymore because this foreign power is so strong.

Comment: I'd just pull an [Operation Nifty Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Nifty_Package) and play "Never Gonna Give You Up" on a loop at deafening volume.

Comment: Anything that disturb your enemy. Piano cat might not be bad against western people but write "Free falafel with every order" in arabic and terror will spread.

Comment: @user535733 Does this narrow it down?

Comment: Caveat: This is an example, not truth..."In the fable, the legendary U.S. General John J. Pershing once ended a wave of Muslim terrorism in the Philippines by executing prisoners with bullets dipped in pigs’ blood. Other superstitious fighters were so terrified by the prospect of being killed while touching part of a forbidden animal, the story goes, that fighting immediately stopped, for some period of time."

Comment: @Mephistopheles much improved!

Comment: [Memes is the DNA of the soul](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/902/970/98b.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one guideline when it comes to determining anything in psychology. ***Try it out***.   Take unfortunate prisoners. Subject them to the different techniques and measure the amount of adrenaline and cortisol before and after the experiment.

To get accurate results, you must of course observe experimental rules by using control subjects etc.

If you wish, you can release the traumatised victims back to their own troops. They will either be unable to speak or they will tell of the dreadful psychological techniques the enemy has.

Before release, prey on the victim's worst fears by suggesting that the things you have subjected them to are mere trifles compared with what you could have done.

> Room 101 in 1984 by George Orwell "You asked me once, what was in Room
> 101. I told you that you knew the answer already. Everyone knows it. The thing that is in Room 101 is the worst thing in the world."
> http://ffolliet.com/2017/08/03/room-101/

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight bit of confusion in the question.

Psycological Operations (PSYOPS) and Psycological warfare are methods used to affect the arttitudes, behaviours and beliefs of the target audience. PSYOPS can be directed at entire nations or focused soecifically on one person, and Psycological warfare covers a huge range of techniques.

An Internet Meme (or even a non internet meme - think of popular songs or slang phrases that could spread throughout the population before the internet existed) is simply a tool which can be adapted or created to conduct PSYOPS or psycological warfare. In the current age, many memes seem to be created and spread spontaniously, and it is a bit of a truism that attepts to create memes by political parties and organizations tend to fall flat.

The main reason for the seeming spontiaity of memes vs the failure of artificially crafted memes is due to two factors - being able to identify the "target audience" to craft a meme that will attract their attention and motivate them to take action, and the speed of the internet. Large organizatons which do propaganda (i.e. the former USSR, modern Russia, advertizing agencies) spend an inordanate amount of time studying every aspect of their target audiences - what the do, who they do it with, how they do things..the list is enourmous. Messages are carefully crafted to trigger responses in the particular target audience and the methods of dissemination carefully selected to reach the maximum number of people in that audience. This is somewhat like determining that the best way to sell soap is to target the women who clean house during the afternoon when they are taking a break and listening to the radio (hence "Soap Opera"). It does not matter if you don't listen to soap operas - you're not the target.

However, this very meticulous, and quite sucessful process takes a huge amount of time and resources, can only react quickly to what they already know (i.e. their understanding of the audience and environment) and often is based on continuing repetition of the messages.

Memes run on "internet time" (i.e. the idea that in one minute, one million people will see it) and the "mud sticking to the wall" effect. If thousands or tens of thousands of people fancy themselves as master meme artists, then millions of memes will flood the Internet every day. Given this sort of number, it is inevitable that some will find a target audience which then amplifies it (reposting etc.). However, since memes are generally crafted spontaniously to momentary stimulii (you saw a cat do something funny, made a meme and posted it), the all important "action" component needed for PSYOPS and Psycological warfare is missing. Funny cat memes don't impel you to do what *I* want you to do.

In order for memes to work in the way suggested, they need to be treated as one tool in the tool kit, and specialists given themes to work on, so they can create and flood particular audiences with memes crafted to get the audience to take some sort of action. The "meme team" may have to produce hundreds of memes to get one to "stick", and then do the same tomorrow and the next day and the day after that....

So the target audience needs to be understood extremely well to identify what motivates or demotivates them, as well as how to reach them, and then a team of people need to be able to take images, ideas and craft memes and rapidly post them in order to reach and affect the target audience. If they are smart enough to do this using fluffy cat videos, all the more power to them. The likely response, however, is adversary cyber operations to identify and block your ISP's and counter memes to blanket the target audience against your product, or your own soldiers receiving fluffy cat videos as well.

Comment: "Funny cat memes don't impel you to do what I want you to do." Yes but making fun of a certain person or group may dissuade people from supporting them.Additionally posting fake news about a certain CEO doing awful things can cause a dip in their sales and send a message to other companies to support your political campaigns.

Comment: Those are *messages*. If you are clever and know your target audience, then you might be able to turn the message into a meme (think "*Crooked Hillary*" in the 2016 US election - two word nickname encapsulates the theme and message of corruption and mistrust to American voters).

Answer (score 0):

**An internet Meme is a viral image that, purely through social sharing, develops popular meaning.**

The power of one therefore is only realised *after* it has been shared. For every viral meme you see, there are thousands yet unrealised.

So you shouldn't put the cart before the horse. First see what memes have gone viral, then use it for your own purposes by adopting it into your branding / manipulation strategy. This means you're not trying to push something that doesn't exist.

I should comment that it is likely best if the meme you use is already present within the enemy territory, not your own, so they see the symbol has meaning. It may not be particularly scary, the meaning is attributed afterwards.

Of course this occurred before the Internet. For instance, the Swastika was a pretty inconspicuous symbol prior to the Nazi's widespread use, and of course, now it's very presence has enormous cultural and (fearful) implications:

[image]

Similarly, this simple image of Che Guevara is now a symbol of Revolutionary thought, and contributed vastly to not just his cause but the cause of many a disestablishmentarian organisation and individuals alike since its creation:

[image]

The use of this image has long represented every revolutionary movement since the [photo was taken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerrillero_Heroico) in 1960. It is so powerful you could say that simply dropping leaflets with this image throughout enemy territory may actually incite revolution.

So your meme can be a symbol or a photo to strike fear or galvanise your populace - preferably pre-existing. Keep in mind that in turn they may create ones of their own, and you have a little Meme war on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

**Use purported enemy-hurting psyops to actually help your own troops.**

/ Should I play Wagner or Tchaikovsky while peppering the enemy with lead from a helicopter?/

Ah, the inscrutable enemy.  Who knows what makes them tick, the weirdos.  Their mothers raised them wrong, every one of them.  That is why they must be destroyed.

But you know what your own soldiers *think* is scary to the enemy.  If you dont, it is definitely easier to find out.   Find out what your warriors think will freak out the other side and do that.  Whether they are right or not about the enemy, morale will go up when they see you put their ideas in play because 1: you listened! and 2: they are certain Bad Guys really do fear Wagner and so are more confident going into battle.